Problema al grabar un registro en mi base de datos, no me actualiza un campo que es una llave foranea
Cuando intento grabar un registro con el controlador store me graba todos los campos menos uno, el campo es una llave foránea. Tengo otros campos similares pero ninguno me da error.
Cuando utilizo el controlador update si me funciona.
lo he probado con Thunder client y no me funciona tampoco:
{
"color":"#FF3333",
"contacts_id":209,
"created_by_id": "cd074481-272c-40f9-bf2a-cb605eb57c13",
"customer_id":null,
"description": "as dasdasdasd",
"end":"2024-05-09 08:27:47",
"ending_type":"date",
"finish":"2024-05-09",
"frequency":"diaria",
"notice_time":"",
"number_repetition":1,
"priority":"BAJA",
"properties_id":null,
"start":"2024-05-09 08:27:47",
"status":"NO INICIADO",
"task_type_id":6,
"title":"asaasdas das",
"users_id":3,
"with_notification":false
}
me genera el registro pero ese campo lo pone en null a pesar que tiene datos,
"contacts_id":209,
Que debo de revisar?

que tengan el mismo tipo

como dijo @Francisco Nuñez IA Lover , que tengan el mismo tipo (primero) , después podrías fijarte en tu modelo , si el campo "contacts_id" se encuentra en el array $fillable . Muchas veces se nos olvida actualizar el modelo para permitir que se graben los campos correctos

Gracias!! lo solucione.
